# Как правильно оформить поиск по сайту?

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь организовать поиск на сайте по одной моделе (таблице) как кому нравится и вывод полученных данных через ActiveDataProvider таким образом

```
public function actionSearch($query)
    {
        $search = Serial::find()->where(['or',['like', 'name_serial', $query],['like', 'description_serial', $query]])->limit(30);
        $searchDataprovider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $search,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 15,
            ],
        ]);
        return $this->render('search', [
            'searchDataprovider' => $searchDataprovider
        ]);
    }
```

если пишу Игра престолов все получаю и вот сразу же оформляю запрос в дебуге

```
SELECT * FROM `fl_serial` WHERE (`name_serial` LIKE '%Игра престолов%') OR (`description_serial` LIKE '%Игра престолов%') LIMIT 15
```

если же  Елизавета I  Лагерь X то ни чего не получаю вообще вот такой запрос в дебуге получаю не объясните как мне правильно оформить

```
SELECT * FROM `fl_serial` WHERE (`name_serial` LIKE '%Елизавета I%') OR (`description_serial` LIKE '%Елизавета I%') LIMIT 15
```

попробовал сделать так

```
public function actionSearch($query)
    {

        $search = Serial::find()->where(['or',['like', 'name_serial', str_replace(' ','%',$query)],['like', 'description_serial', str_replace(' ','%',$query)]])->limit(30);
        $searchDataprovider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $search,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 15,
            ],
        ]);
        return $this->render('search', [
            'searchDataprovider' => $searchDataprovider
        ]);
    }
```

получаю такой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `fl_serial` WHERE (`name_serial` LIKE '%Елизавета//%I%') OR (`description_serial` LIKE '%Елизавета//%I%') LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в кодировке, символ I(Елизавета I), если бы вы использовали цифру 1 вместо латинской I то по моему был бы успех.
Хотя я не уверен ,по моему должно было работать.

Я тебе советую использовать fulltext index.

MySQL 5.5 пользовался движком MyISAM,
если у вас версия выше то движок InnoDB уже поддерживает fulltext.

ниже  я приведу пример моего кода ,которым я не раз пользовался.

1. Создать процедуру с именем search_result
2. Создать в нем таблицу если ее нету на движке MyISAM
3. Повесить на колонки по которым будет выборка fulltext index
4. заполнить таблицу на основе выборки из таблицы данных которые нас интересуют
5. морфологическая выборка по fulletext с использованным коэффициента совпадения
6. Потом почистить данные из нее повесив на движок  blackhole
7. после запустить процедуру
8. И у нас будет полноценный морфологический поиск

   $sql =  call search_result('aaa bbb ccc'), call
   search_result('Елизавета I')

   $sql = call search_result('Елизавета I') выведет Елизавета I,I Елизавета ...

Да не забываем поменять настройку в MySql my.ini fayl ft_min_word_len = 2.
этот ключ позволяет искать слова в два символа,по умолчанию по моему 4.

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE PROCEDURE search_result(IN search_data VARCHAR(255), IN user_id INT(11))
BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS searchTableRes (
            `id` INT NOT NULL,
            `type` VARCHAR(255),
            `user_name` VARCHAR(255),
            `content` TEXT,
            `created_at` VARCHAR(255)
        )ENGINE=MYISAM;

        INSERT INTO searchTableRes (
          `id`,
          `type`,
          `user_name`,
          `content`,
          `created_at`
        )
        SELECT 
           `e`.`id` AS `id`,
           'event' AS `type`,
           CONCAT(`u`.`first_name`,' ',`u`.`last_name`) AS `user_name`,
          `e`.`description` AS `content`,
          `e`.`created_at` AS `created_at`
        FROM `events` `e`
        INNER JOIN `users` `u` 
            ON `u`.`id` = `e`.`user_id`
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(user_id,`e`.`users`);


        CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ixFull ON searchTableRes (`type`,`user_name`,`content`,`created_at`);

        SELECT *,MATCH(`type`,`user_name`,`content`,`created_at`) 
                                  AGAINST (CONCAT('*',search_data,'*') IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS coefficient
                  FROM searchTableRes
                                WHERE MATCH(`type`,`user_name`,`content`,`created_at`) 
                                                AGAINST (CONCAT('*',search_data,'*') IN BOOLEAN MODE)
                                                    ORDER BY coefficient DESC;
        ALTER table searchTableRes ENGINE = BLACKHOLE;

END
||
DELIMITER ;
```

Можете доработать его под свои нужды

Comment: Проблема в том что я не смогу (потому что не знаю как) сформировать этот код в yii2

Comment: otkrivaesh mysql monitor ,posle dorabotki pod svoi nujdi ,dobavlyaesh proceduru,a potom gde tebe nado v kodeYii::app()->db->createCommand(call search_result("Елизавета I"));
Predpologayu chto to yii1 frameqork